# Modifying script: NameError: name '' is not defined

Tags: python, nameerror, defined

I am having problems with modifying a code written by someone else. Basically, trying to get the script to read a list of inputs(gene names) but I'm getting the following error:

> NameError: name 'gene_name' is not defined

Below is the code:

```
import csv

fullout = np.empty((1,3704))

def gene_list(gene_name):
    gene_list = open('C:\Users\Work\Desktop\Book1.csv', 'rU'), f
    gene_list = []
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        gene_name = "row.strip()"

for gene_name in gene_list(gene_name):
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        with gene_list:
            reader = csv.reader(f)
        for row in reader: 
            gene_name = row
            probes_dict = get_probes_from_genes(gene_name)
        expression_values, well_ids, donor_names = get_expression_values_from_probe_ids_hdf(
                probes_dict.keys())
        print get_mni_coordinates_from_wells(well_ids)`
```

Comment: The error means exactly what it says. You haven't defined `gene_name` anywhere.

Comment: You are trying to use `gene_name` before it is defined. `gene_name` is only defined INSIDE the for loop after the line you tried to bold...not on the line

Comment: What should i do then? Because the gene_name value is derived from that .csv file, do I define it with a separate def then? What will it look like?

Comment: what exactly is gene_name supposed to be in your loop?

Comment: Gene_name is supposed to be a string, i.e. the gene in the 1st row of the .csv file is "Gene ABC", and this should be the input to the for loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`gene_name` is defined inside the scope of the function, as remarked by Padraic Cunningham. Once the function is over, you can't use this variable anymore.

I recommend you to read the docs about scopes. [Scopes and Namespaces](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces)

Comment: That is not really correct, it is in the scope of the function, you could access the last value outside the loop.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I mistook with other languages, I will edit the post. Thank you!